# Find type of groovy/grails property

Tags: grails, groovy

I am editing the scaffolding templates for a grails application.

One of my domain classes has the following property:

```
Set<GlobalRole> globalRoles
```

where GlobalRole is an enum. The link is one-to-many:

```
static hasMany = [globalRoles: GlobalRole]
```

As default scaffolding shows the roles as a comma separated string - my aim is to show it as a list. To this aim I need to find out if a property (globalRoles) is of type Set to differentiate the generation of the scaffolding.

```
if (User.globalRoles.type instanceof Set){ 
    // do something else
}
```

However: this statement is 'falsified' and therefore not working.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to get the static `User.globalRoles` field which is wrong of course. You shall be using reflection / meta-programming:

```
if( User.hasMetaProperty( 'globalRoles' ) && Set.inAssignableFrom( User.getMetaProperty( 'globalRoles' ).type ){
```

Comment: thank you. however i solved it with `if (p.type == java.util.Set)`